# How to crop a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, properties, crop

I need to crop a div to fit the size of an image, and be placed on top of it.
Basically I'm trying to draw a black box on an image I have on a webpage.

Code:

```
<div class="col-9" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <div class="itemscenter" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 4px;">
        <img style="width: 85%" src="../Images/fov110.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

I made a border then tried cutting the div.
I also used a width percent thing.

Comment: `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: You want the `div` to be the same size as the image it contains? I think `width: min-content` would work. You want the `div` to be positioned on top of the image that is inside the `div`? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: You could probably approach this in a simpler way. You just need one div with an image in it, sizing it with `object-fit` and positioning it with `object-position`. The black square over the image could be served up with the `::before` or `::after` pseudo elements. You could also use a background image if the image is just for decoration. But to be honest, it's not quite clear what you are trying to do. Maybe an image would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the outside div smaller and set the image's width to 100%

Comment: Well, is it still possible to crop the div? For other reasons...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you need to set height of image according to your reqirement.

```
<div class="col-9 d-flex justify-content-center">
<div class="itemscenter" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 4px;">
    <img src="../Images/fov110.png">
</div>
</div>

css

.itemscenter img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
```